# Is CUDA optimising this Code Badly or am I wrong?

Tags: c++, optimization, cuda

Here is a block of Code I have been working on and have been recieving a result I didn't expect. I've cut down my full code block to just highlight the problem. I expect that at the end of this block `spID` should be a block of `tid` values with the exception of those pixels where `lbBool` is `true` where `spID` should be `_CCL_SHARED_MEM_MAX_VALUE (255)`. However If I use NSight to debug the data at the `__syncthreads()` I find all the `spID` values equivalent to where `lbBool` was `true` are 0.

My blocks are composed of 16 by 16 threads so `uint8` is sufficient for storing all the values (0-255). I realise that there will be a single valid pixel with the ID 255 and a load of dead pixels with a Value of 255. That is fine.

I'm using `unsigned long` for `tOut`.

In this case my Image is 100x100 but it fails on each image size I've tried.
I'm running on a GTX 580 and regularly use kernels with 256 threads.

Calling the Kernel:

```
#define _CCL_SHARED_MEM_TYPE uint8
#define _CCL_SHARED_MEM_MAX_VALUE 255

template<class tOut> tOut *nsGPUBaseClasses::IbxCCL4Link(bool *lbEdges,uint32 liImageWidth,uint32 liImageHeight,tOut *lpOut)
{
dim3 liThreads(16,16);
dim3 liBlocks((liImageWidth+liThreads.x-1)/liThreads.x,(liImageHeight+liThreads.y-1)/liThreads.y);

if(lpOut == nullptr) _CHECK_CUDA_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&lpOut,sizeof(tOut)*liImageWidth*liImageHeight));

IbxCCL4LinkCUDA<<<liBlocks,liThreads,(sizeof(_CCL_SHARED_MEM_TYPE)*liThreads.x*liThreads.y+sizeof(bool)*2)>>>(lbEdges,liImageWidth,liImageHeight,lpOut);

_CHECK_CUDA_ERROR_EMPTY();

return lpOut;
}
```

And the Kernel Itself:

```
template<class tOut> void __global__ IbxCCL4LinkCUDA(bool *lbBool,unsigned long liImageWidth,unsigned long liImageHeight,tOut *lpOut)
{
    // Shared Memory
    __shared__ float lbSpecific[];
    _CCL_SHARED_MEM_TYPE *spID=reinterpret_cast<_CCL_SHARED_MEM_TYPE*>(&lbSpecific);

    //IDs for thread
    unsigned long tid = threadIdx.x+threadIdx.y*blockDim.x;
    unsigned long liXPos = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    unsigned long liYPos = (threadIdx.y+blockIdx.y*blockDim.y);

    //Check if it is in image bounds
    if(liXPos>=liImageWidth || liYPos>=liImageHeight) return;
    unsigned long liPPos = liXPos+liYPos*liImageWidth;

    //If Boolean is true
    if(lbBool[liPPos]) 
    {
        spID[tid] = _CCL_SHARED_MEM_MAX_VALUE;      
        lpOut[liPPos] =liImageWidth*liImageHeight;
        return;
    }
    lpOut = &lpOut[liPPos];
    lpOut[0] = (blockIdx.x+blockIdx.y*gridDim.x)*(_CCL_SHARED_MEM_MAX_VALUE+1);

    spID[tid] = tid;
    __syncthreads();

    //More Processing Goes Here

    lpOut[0] += static_cast<tOut>(spID[tid]);
}
```

Should this be outputting 255 or 0 in equivalent locations to `lbBool` being `true`?
If it is zero is this Cuda optimising out the write to shared memory?
Is there a way I can make the boolean check set the Value to 255?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shared memory allocation is broken.  `__shared__ float lbSpecific;` allocates ONE floating point value.  You then set `spID` to that address, and use locations far beyond the single floating point allocation.

Just allocate the shared memory you want, with the correct size and type, and skip the typecast.

```
__shared__ _CCL_SHARED_MEM_TYPE spID[TOTAL_BLOCK_SIZE];
```

Comment: I have made corrections as noted here. I was previously declaring a shared memory block in the Kernel call, but not calling it as a pointer. Will make the correction and test, but I suspect it will not fix the issue as all the other values were working correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were entirely correct. Thank you for the answer.